# JobPosting schema issue: Number is not a known valid target type for the baseSalary property

Tags: schema.org, microdata, structured-data

I'm a little confused about the new JobPosting listing on schema.org, specifically the baseSalary property's expected type.

The docs say that Number is one of the three expected types:

[schema JobPosting SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMbXd.png)

But when I test the page on Google structured data testing tool I get this warning:

[Google warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06ey0.png)

stating that 'Number is not a known valid target type for the baseSalary property.'

Nothing weird in the code, just a simple span with the baseSalary itemprop:

```
<span itemprop="baseSalary">36000</span>
```

Am I misunderstanding this or missing something?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

This is **not** [schema.org](https://schema.org/) error. This issue related specifically to google validator & rich snippets **recommended** properties/guidelines (I agree that an error message does not contribute too much information).

For rich results - Google Required `MonetaryAmount` as a type for [baseSalary](https://schema.org/baseSalary) (**Not** number)

```
"baseSalary": {
  "@type": "MonetaryAmount",
  "currency": "USD",
  "value": {
    "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
    "value": 40.00,
    "unitText": "HOUR"
  }
}
```

**Docs & examples:**
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/job-posting
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wants to use HTML elements for the `baseSalary` instead of `ld+json` schema:

```
<span itemprop="baseSalary" itemtype="https://schema.org/MonetaryAmount" itemscope>
    <span itemprop="value" itemtype="https://schema.org/QuantitativeValue" itemscope>
        <span itemprop="value">30</span>
        <span itemprop="unitText">HOUR</span>
    </span>
    <span itemtype="https://schema.org/salaryCurrency" itemprop="currency">USD</span>
</span>
```